# Containing super messy table-based HTML layout

Tags: html, html-table, footer

I am trying to add a footer to a table-based HTML layout that has numerous nested tables.  The structure looks something like this:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      bloody mess of <table><tr><td> tags
    </form>
--- div footer to go here ----
</body>
```

The DIV footer ends up hanging behind the main table about 1/4 of the way down... I assume that means some table/row/cell tags are not closed properly...

I tried putting divs around the form, hoping that would force the browser to auto-close all unclosed tags.  That did not work.

I would prefer to re-write the whole thing, but the page is not documented, very complex, and has numerous includes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without the offending HTML, no one can really guess.

Comment: +1 for "bloody mess of `table` tags". I take it you've inherited this abomination?

Comment: Diodeus - The HTML file is about 12,000 lines... I am not looking for a guess. I am hoping for some helpful ideas from somebody who has experience dealing with the way browsers treat broken HTML or somebody who had to contain messy HTML.

Comment: JamWaffles - yes this is inherited... This thing has tables 5+ layers deep.  If this were my creation, I would have to rip my own arms out and slap myself with them.

Comment: Slapping yourself with your own arms... Interestingly plural!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check whether your tags are correctly closed you may way to [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/).

Without seeing your code it's difficult to guess at what the problem could be but here's a sugestion.

The table could be floated using CSS or positioned absolutely (`position:absolute`). If this is the case you may need to remove the float or positon.

Given that your layout is currently table based, and given that you're not re-writing the whole thing, the easiest option may be to add an extra table row at the bottom for your footer.

Comment: Yep, one of the higher-level tables was styled as position:absolute.  Other components were floating, so that table just went on top of them.  The footer jumped to the bottom once I removed the position:absolute.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let the browser parse the page, and dynamically insert your `<div>` using Javascript's DOM access:

[`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.createElement)

[`node.insertAfter`](http://www.netlobo.com/javascript-insertafter.html)

This way, the browser will parse the "bloody mess". This does not guarantee browser compatibility, however, as it depends on how each different browser parses the "mess".

Comment: Thank you Pindatjuh, this is an interesting and innovative idea... but I will accept the position:absolute answer because it led me to to the solution.